# Fundamental matrix of OED.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi(t)$ be a $n \times n$ matrix whose elements are functions of class $C ^ 1$, no singular for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists a unique matrix $A(t)$ continuous such that $\phi(t)$ is fundamental matrix of $x' = A(t)x$

Comment: What's your definition of _fundamental matrix_? In my course it had to satisfy initial data $\phi(0)=Id$. By the way, try $A(t)=\phi'(t)\phi^{-1}(t)$.

Comment: Fundamental matrix  is a matrix nxn whose columns form a basis of the solution space.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I think requiring the condition $\phi(0)=I$ makes it a *special matrix*, usually.

Comment: @GitGud it's a terminology question, further diluted by translation from russian to english=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set
$$
A(t)=\phi'(t)\phi^{-1}(t).
$$